# Tensorflow: dynamic linking with shared library

Tags: c++, tensorflow, shared-libraries, bazel

I'm doing a shared library which uses Tensorflow. For now I placed it in Tensorflow's source tree as subproject with the following BUILD file:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "recognizer.so",
    srcs = glob(["recognizer.cpp"]),
    linkshared = 1,
    deps = [
        "//tensorflow:сore"
    ],
)
```

Everything links together but I end up with a shared library about 94 megabytes in size and not depended on libtensorflow_cc.so. Actually there is even no such binary as libtensorflow_cc.so built.

There is a target //tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so . It is declared as cc_binary which means (according to bazel) I cannot depend on it. Moreover this target is actually non-public, which means that I can build it but not refer to it from another subproject. At least with bazel.

So, is there any way to do such a simple thing?

Comment: What OS are you on? What `--cpu` flag value, if any, do you pass to Bazel?

Comment: I'm on Linux. No --cpu flag was passed to Bazel

Comment: So you want to build your custom code as a shared library that depends on libtensorflow_cc.so?

Comment: mhlopko, as you say in German - genau )

Answer (score 3):

I cannot comment on why libtensorflow.so or libtensorflow_cc.so are :internal. But there is a trick you can do in Bazel to be able to depend on a shared library created by cc_binary: declare it as a source of a cc rule.

```
cc_binary(
    name = "liba.so",
    srcs = [ "a.cc" ],
    linkshared = 1
)

cc_binary(
    name = "main",
    srcs = [ "main.cc", "liba.so" ],
)
```

Now this is highly unsupported :) In fact, we are going to change how we handle shared libraries in the following months, so I can almost promise you it will break. You can subscribe to https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/1920 or follow bazel-dev@ to be updated.

Comment: # LCM shared libraries path
cc_binary(
    name = "liblcm.so",
    srcs = ["lib/liblcm.so"],
    copts = ["-I/usr/local/lib"],
    linkopts = ["-pthread"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

I am trying to include my liblcm.so into my build file, but bazel tells me I am missing the input file lcm/liblcm.so. I tried your method above of converting it .cc file, but that did not work for me

Comment: That sounds like a separate issue, can you create a question and provide more context?